# Is there a way to compare parts of an object in Java, w/o using a sort API?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am a student in a beginning Java class, and I have been stuck for quite a while on this, so I thought I might ask and see if anyone could help me.

I have an array made up of objects of student information, that have a String name, an int age, and a double gpa.  My assignment calls for me to sort this array by the gpa, so the highest gpa is first.  And then I have to print the new sorted array.

My professor said not to use API sort.  So I am trying to use loops to traverse the array, but I do not know how to compare only the gpa fields and then re-order the entire object by the gpa score.  Here is my code so far, based upon the teacher's suggestion, but it won't compile and I am at a loss as how to proceed or what direction to go in.  Thanks in advance for any help you maybe able to provide.

```
    int i, j; // used to index into the array
    Student temp;

    for (i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        temp = students[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && temp < students[j]) 
        {
            students[j + 1] = students[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        students[j + 1] = temp;
    }
```

Here is the Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double gpa;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Student
 */
public Student(String n, int a, double g) 
{
    // initialise instance variables
    name = n;
    age = a;
    gpa = g;
}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     the sum of x and y 
 */
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%s %s %s",name,age,gpa); 
}
```

}

Comment: Let's put away the syntax for a moment and get a piece of paper.  Write out what it is that you're trying to sort (be specific; use the fields instead of the actual objects).  Determine how you're going to sort these values (you can do hand-written implementations of bubble sort or mergesort to accomplish this).

Comment: I hate to show my ignorance yet again, but I am not sure what bubble sort or mergesort is.  I have written it down though, trying to figure it out, but the biggest problem I keep coming to is not knowing how to compare just the gpa part of each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing the comparison, you are storing the student object in `temp`. Instead just store the gpa in temp, so `tmp = students[i].getGPA()` (or whatever your accessor for gpa is) and compare it against `students[j].getGPA()`. You can still swap the students themselves, just compare the GPA.

Also, as for the actual sorting, there are a variety of sorting algorithms you can use (bubble, selection, merge, quicksort, etc). I have not verified the correctness of your sort algorithm, but the more efficient sort algorithms are not n^2 complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate it.  How can I get at the gpa field, when I make the getGPA method?  I apologize if that is a ridiculous question.

Comment: Can you post the `Student` class and we can help show you how?

Comment: Ok, I added it to the first post.

Comment: Just add a `getGPA` method that returns the private field `gpa`.

Comment: Oh...let me try that.  Thank you!